# Make page clone not accecible anymore via URL

Tags: python, typescript, flask, next.js

I am trying to create a game on a website using `Next JS` for the FrontEnd and `Flask` for the BackEnd.

My problems are as follows:

1. After I click cancel the custom room page redirects me back to the main screen but I still can access the custom room page, I want it deleted when I click cancel **(The cancel button is in the footer which I did not include here)**
2. If I type a custom ID myself in the URL, e.g. localhost/room/ let's say `112HDC` -> `localhost/room/112HDC` It would open a custom room with that URL which I don't want it to.

This is the code so far for the page (front and back end).

#### NewPage/index.tsx

```
import { onGameStart } from "@/services/backendService";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { useEffect } from "react";

const NewPage = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  const redirect = async () => {
    const code = await onGameStart();
    router.push(`/room/${code}`);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    redirect();
  }, [redirect]);

  return <div></div>;
};

export default NewPage;
```

#### RoomPage/index.tsx

```
import CustomContainer from "@/components/atoms/CustomContainer";
import { Divider, Text } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { useEffect } from "react";

const RoomPage = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const roomId = router.query.id?.toString();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (roomId) {
      console.log(roomId);
    }
  }, [roomId]);

  return (
    <CustomContainer justifyContent={"start"} pt={"2em"} gap={1}>
      <Divider w={"29em"} opacity={"0.2"} />
      <Text fontSize={"2.7em"}>{roomId}</Text>
      <Text fontSize={"1.3em"}>{"Ugly Fish Bite Yearly"}</Text>
      <Divider w={"29em"} opacity={"0.2"} />
    </CustomContainer>
  );
};

export default RoomPage;
```

#### services/backendservices.tsx

```
import axios from "axios";
import { SERVER_URL, WEB_URL } from "@/constants";

export const onGameStart = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get(`${SERVER_URL}/lobby`);
    return res.data.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

export const onGameCancel = async () => {
  const path = window.location.pathname;
  const match = path.match(/\/room\/(\w+)/);
  if (match) {
    const code = match[1];
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(`${SERVER_URL}/game/cancel/${code}`, { code });
      const data = response.data;
      if (data.success) {
        history.pushState(null, '', '/');
        window.location.reload()
        //window.location.href = `${WEB_URL}`;
      } else {
        // Handle the case where the game could not be cancelled
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      // Handle the case where the game could not be cancelled
    }
  }
};

export const onGameJoin = async () => {
  const code = document.getElementById("GameInput") as HTMLInputElement;
  if (code.value.length > 6){
    //handle inporper code.
    return
  }
  try {
    const res = await axios.get(`${SERVER_URL}/join/`);
    return res.data.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

#### backend/app.py

```
from controller.rest_controller import RestAPI

app = RestAPI().app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

#### backend/controller/rest_controller.py

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_cors import CORS
from logic.game_logic import Game

class RestAPI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = Flask(__name__)
        CORS(self.app)

        @self.app.route("/")
        def hello_world():
            return "<p>Hello, World!</p>"

        @self.app.route("/lobby", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
        def lobby():
            game = Game()
            if request.method == 'GET':
                url = game.generate_custom_url()
                return jsonify(
                    statusCode=200,
                    message="success",
                    isError=False,
                    data=url
                )
        @self.app.route('/game/cancel/<code>', methods=['POST'])
        def cancel_game(code):
            if request.method == 'POST':
                # data = request.get_json()
                try: 
                    Game.on_lobby_close(URL=code)
                    return jsonify({'success': True})
                except ValueError:
                    return jsonify({'success': False})
            

    def run(self):
        self.app.run(host='192.168.1.20', port=5000)


app = RestAPI().app
```

#### backend/logic/game_logic.py

```
import random
from .stack import Stack

ACTIVE_URLS = []

class Game:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.CARDS_DICT: dict = {
            # There is data here I chose to delete it for now.
        }
        self.cards = Stack(
            # There is data here I chose to delete it for now.
            )
        self.players = [] # Stores the users connected to the game.
    def generate_custom_url(self) -> str:
        """
            | [HttpGet]
            | Use when user creates a lobby.
        """
        url = ""
        values = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" + "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".upper() + "1234567890"
        for _ in range(6):
            letter = random.randint(0, len(values)-1)
            url += values[letter]

        ACTIVE_URLS.append(url)
        print(ACTIVE_URLS)
        return url

    @staticmethod
    def on_lobby_close(URL: str) -> None:
        """
            | [HttpPost]
            | Use when a lobby gets closed.
        """
        ACTIVE_URLS.remove(URL) 
        print(ACTIVE_URLS)
```